# Socket Server throwing "Socket is closed" after uploading files

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Java server uploading files for the android client. It does the upload but when it is finished, it keeps throwing:

```
Error::java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

I searched the code a lot, but didn't find anything. Since it is throwing after uploading the files, I think problem is at the end of code after last for loop, but I see nothing wrong. Any ideas guys?

```
class ClientThread extends Thread {
  // the socket where to listen/talk
  String Type;
  Socket socket;
  ObjectInputStream sInput;
  ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
  // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
  int id;

  // Constructore
  ClientThread(Socket socket) throws InterruptedException {
    // a unique id
    id = ++uniqueId;
    this.socket = socket;
    /* Creating both Data Stream */
    System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
    while (!jobdone) {
      try {
        // create output first
        sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        // read the username
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

        String Request = (String) sInput.readObject();
        System.out.println(Request);

        String[] todoname = Request.split("\\@reza-hp");
        String name = todoname[0];
        System.out.println("Connecting...");

        File fil = new File("D://Users//ProfileImages//reza");

        System.out.println(fil);
        File[] Files = fil.listFiles();
        System.out.println(Files);
        for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {
          System.out.println(Files[count].getName());

        }

        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

        dos.writeInt(Files.length);

        for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {
          dos.writeUTF(Files[count].getName());

        }
        for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {

          int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();
          dos.writeInt(filesize);
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {

          int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();
          byte[] buffer = new byte[filesize];

          fis = new FileInputStream(Files[count].toString());
          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

          // Sending file name and file size to the server
          bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // This line is
                                              // important
          dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
          dos.flush();
          fis.close();
        }

        dos.close();
        os.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error::" + e);
      }
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Server.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace please and mark the line the exception comes from.

Comment: You seem to create a lot of input/output streams unnecessarily. `sOutput` is never used. `os` and `dos` are created twice, for some reason.

Comment: Is the socket re-used in other threads? The currently accepted answer suggests removing `close()` calls, which might be a valid approach if you plan to use this same socket elsewhere.

Comment: You have both `dos.close();` and `os.close()`. Could you add a print statement between them and another one after second. If I am right, you should see only first and exception should occur on `os.close()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your socket is getting closed from Otherside

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ServerSocket` to listen for incoming connections from your client application. Plain `Socket` is preatty straightforward. Open connection, exchange data, close connection, dispose. You could rebind your socket, but this is not the way you should do.

```
ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(yourPort);
Socket clientSocket=server.listen(); // here you will block until incoming connection
```

Check docs for more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)